# How to generate random numbers with rand() without time.h in C

Tags: c, random, numbers, srand

How to generate random numbers with rand() and srand() without time.h in C ?

Comment: You (optionally) call `srand` and then you call `rand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try givin another seed to the random generator like the program's pid.

```
srand(getpid());
int num = rand();
```